# Disable SSL verification on Hsts

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, openssl

When i try to run

```
openssl s_client -connect www.merdincz.com:443 -debug
```

command i'm getting;

```
SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error
```

On SSLLabs https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=merdincz.com everything seems perfect. Probably i'm getting this error because of Hsts.

Is there a way on openssl skip verification for hsts ?

I've tried

```
openssl s_client -connect www.merdincz.com:443 -verify false -debug
```

command too but nothing changed.

Comment: Doubt it's anything to do with HSTS. What version of openssl are you running?

Comment: @BazzaDP i'm using OpenSSL 1.0.1l-freebsd 15 Jan 2015